# Unable to follow fix (importing a java project) for hiDPI screens using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, projects

I recently bought a 4K, hiDPI laptop for coding throughout college. The only problem is that the icons in Eclipse are appearing very small. I did some research and came across this fix. According to the author, all you have to do is setup his project in Eclipse and run the program, and all of the icons will be enlarged. The problem is that I only really understand Java, and his code involves outside resources. I'm having a really difficult time importing the project and running it without errors. Can someone help me and give me the steps to properly import the project and run it error free?

Link to project: https://github.com/davidglevy/eclipse-icon-enlarger

Answer (score 1):

This problem is being addressed in Eclipse Neon. Please try Neon RC builds either from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

N&N for Neon is available here http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php

Answer (score 0):

I have yesterday's build of Eclipse Photon and it still had all the HiDPI issues. Really annoying until I found a solution for me:

Eclipse.exe > Properties > Compatibility > Change high DPI settings > Override High DPI (on) > System (enhanced)

[Win10 Compatibility settings for HiDPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLL2.png) (PNG on Imgur)